# JSP & mysql throws java.lang.classNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I have the same problem that but it is Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to execute a web page with the help of JSP & mysql as a database. After execution in tomcat logs it gives the error of

> "java.lang.classNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.driver"

The hint that I got is that I have to keep my `mysql-connector.jar` file somewhere such that my tomcat will able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Driver` class name need to be capitalized. Use like

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

instead of

```
com.mysql.jdbc.driver
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can Use `Driver` instead of `driver`

**or**

- If you get this error when you are running it, then probably its because you have not included mysql-connector JAR file to your webserver's lib folder. you can Easily Check on Class Path as well . may be jar File Broken . `Right Click the project -- > build path -- > configure build path`

Thanks